# Can’t link to MS Azure account

Tags: azure, docker, docker-cloud

The documentation for [linking a MS Azure account](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/infrastructure/link-azure/) appears to drastically differ from the actual Docker Cloud UI:

[image: Azure Link screen]

How can I link my Docker Cloud account with my MS Azure account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can link our Docker Cloud account with MS Azure account via cloud docker portal:

Select "**Swarm mode**", then follow the [article](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/infrastructure/link-azure/) to link Azure account.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping!